# iOS app startup animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I want to insert in my app a startup animation, after the default image disappears.  In my app, I have a navigation bar and a tab bar, so I have tried to put this in the view did load:

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myIMG.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:img];
```

Then, I want to animate that image with a transition, but with the image I positioned in the view, between the tab bar and the nav bar, and I want the the image in front of all to start the animation.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

1. Create a view controller named startup view controller.
2. In AppDelegate when app start, set this view is rootViewController
3. Do some animation with your image or whatever you want while loading data or connecting to server.
4. When everything done, from this start up view controller, you can remove this start up view and show your main view by call app delegate to set your main view controller is root view controller.

[Edit]

In case you only want the imageView can cover all the screen, then you can do as following:

```
[appDelegate.window addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want during the animation that my masterview controller is show in the background

Comment: In case you only want the imageView can cover all the screen, then you can do as following: [appDelegate.window addSubview:imageView];

Answer (score 2):

1. Create View Controller for your startup animation
2. In App Delegate , show your startup View Controller

**In AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ....
    ....
    ....
    frontScreen *animScreen =   [[frontScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"frontScreen" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = animScreen;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

1. After finished animation, call show tabview controller

**In frontScreen.m**

```
AppDelegate* app =(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  [app afterAnimation];
```

**In AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)afterAnimation {
    rootController *list=[[rootController alloc] initWithNibName:@"rootController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:list];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; //optional
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want during the animation that my masterview controller is show in the background

Answer (score 2):

```
//Display an Ads Imageview with animation on top of View 
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sale2.jpg"]];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.5 animations:^{imageView.alpha = 0;imageView.alpha = 1;}];

[self.window addSubview:imageView];



-(void)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
  //**************Remove the Advertising Image after the user press single tap on the img
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{imageView.alpha = 1;imageView.alpha = 0;}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to cover everything is to create a segue of the Modal style, and fill that segue's view with your animation image, and as the app launches, programmatically call that segue right away, so it is the first thing to appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:img];
```

then your image will show full screen.